# How to force extjs grid to save state

Tags: extjs4

If the user changes a column size, the grid stateManager saves the state of the grid.  However if you provide a reset button and use grid.reconfigure() the state does not get saved.

How do you force the grid to issue a state save with a reconfigure?

Answer (score 1):

You can save the current state any time:

```
grid.saveState();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use grid.initState() just after the reconfigure.
Like below.

```
grid.reconfigure(store, columns);
grid.initState();
```

Eventhough initState() can not find on Ext js documentation this works for with the ver 4.2

Hope this helps

Comment: This does not work by itself. There has to be something more to it.